# Adding attachments to an HTTP POST email via Power Automate

Tags: json, http, post, attachment

Within Power Automate I have a 'no-reply' email being generated automatically (via HTTP POST request) which includes dynamic form data.  The form allows for the upload of up to 10 files (eg images) to SharePoint (Apps/Microsoft Forms).  The files could be of any style eg images, Excel, word etc.  I would like to be able to attach these files to the HTTP POST email.  Is there a way of doing this?

The JSON in the POST message I think can include html content so I am guessing the answer lies somewhere there.  That said, at this point I don't know where to begin so any help would be appreciated.